# NSubstitute method called multiple times with specific sequence of args?

Tags: c#, mocking, nsubstitute

I want to check that a specific method is called N times, first with arg x1, then x2, then x3, etc. and finally with arg xN. I know it could be done like this:

```
Received.InOrder(() => {
    subst.MyMethod(x1);
    subst.MyMethod(x2);
    subst.MyMethod(x3);
    // ...
    subst.MyMethod(xN);
});
```

But can it be done in some way that simply lists the sequence of arguments?

Something like this (conceptual):

```
int[] args = {x1, x2, x3, /*...*/ xN};
subst.Received(N).MyMethod(Arg.Is(args));
```

Here's an implementation with `InOrder` but I consider it a workaround:

```
int[] args = {x1, x2, x3, /*...*/ xN};
Received.InOrder(() => {
    foreach (int i in args)
        subst.MyMethod(i);
});
```

Comment: I've done something similar before but using `Queue<T>` and `queue.Dequeue()`

Comment: The NSubstitute API does not have a method for doing this. To me the `foreach` method is clearest; it shows exactly what is expected for the test to succeed. You could write a method to package up this logic if you need it frequently, but while it may make it a bit more concise I don't think it will make it any clearer.

Comment: @DavidTchepak Thanks! That pretty much closes this question and I'm OK with the `foreach` approach. It's already in place in my unit test. Feel free to write it as an answer, and I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58030610/nsubstitute-method-called-multiple-times-with-specific-sequence-of-args?noredirect=1#comment102476870_58030610) above:

> The NSubstitute API does not have a method for doing this. To me the `foreach` method is clearest; it shows exactly what is expected for the test to succeed. You could write a method to package up this logic if you need it frequently, but while it may make it a bit more concise I don't think it will make it any clearer.